# What do I need from my certificate to use SSL in .NET?

Tags: ssl, x509, sslstream

`The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.`

I have my Base64-encoded *.crt* file and another huge text file with lots of info, from my certificate provider, which includes the private RSA key in an equivalent format.
I tried putting that in a *.pvk* file to later make the *.pfx* one, and it didn't work. (nice try, right?)
What do I need to actually do to use this certificate to use SSL in my .NET application?

**Edit**: Made a proper *.pvk*, made the *.pfx*, still, same error.

Comment: What code are you using so far? How did you try to make the PFX file and how specifically did it "not work"? Is there some reason you can't/won't install the certificate using CertMgr.msc?

Comment: The *.pvk* with text didn't work. The certificate itself doesn't include the private key.

Comment: When you install the PFX file in CertMgr.msc, the private key is imported as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this. I had to use `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` with the *.pfx* file.
The simple `X509Certificate` didn't seem to work.

Comment: The plain X509Certificate only works if there's an associated private key installed in the Windows certificate manager.

Comment: Having to import that manually in every machine that runs the server software is just redundant. Using the `X509Certificate2` is the best solution in my case.